# PHP Xdebug not in php

Tags: php, macos, mamp, xdebug

hi i install homebrew install some brew things and now i need install Xdebug but when i write to terminal on mac `php --version` there is only version of php not version php with xdebug only version of php

```
$ php --version
PHP 7.2.8 (cli) (built: Aug 28 2018 16:32:29) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

help me i doo all things what i should but it not work correctly help thx

Comment: xdebug ususally us loaded as an _extension_ to php, so it is not built into the php engine but loaded at runtime. Have a try using the `phpinfo()` function to find out what modules _are_ actually loaded into your engine and modify the php settings to adjust that.

Answer (score 1):

With the migration to Homebrew-core the php formula has stopped taking over the role of PECL. Installing xdebug can (and should) be done through PECL (https://pecl.php.net/package/xdebug).

`pecl update-channels`

`pecl list-all`

`pecl install xdebug`

or upgrade it

`pecl upgrade xdebug`

After that you'd need to update your php.ini with a line to specify xdebug's location, as suggested on xdebug.org:

`zend_extension="/usr/local/php/modules/xdebug.so"`

Additionally, you may need to put in there some settings for xdebug, for example:

```
xdebug.collect_vars=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9005
```

Source: http://www.artemdwo.com/install-php72-and-xdebug-on-mac-os-x